# Angular ui.router can not assert controller, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wrote a simple Angular application and for my routing i used ui.router, but i am getting this error:

> Argument 'loginController' is not a function, got undefined

modules.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('account', ['ui.router']);
    angular.module('app', ['account', 'ui.router']);
})();
```

routeConfig.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var account = angular.module('account');
    account.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        // For any unmatched url
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
        $stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: '/app/components/account/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController'
            });
    });
})();
```

account.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var account = angular.module('account');
    account.controller('loginController', ['$scope', loginController]);
    function loginController($scope) {
        $scope.Title = 'login';
    };
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>   
    <div ui-view>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app/modules.js"></script>
    <script src="app/routeConfig.js"></script>
    <script src="app/components/account/account.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html:

```
<h4>{{Title}}</h4>
```

I'm new to ui.router, and the error come from route config.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Replace this line`account.controller('loginController', ['$scope', loginController]);` to `account.controller('loginController', 'loginController');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use injection, that's not the way to do it.

If your function is separate from `account.controller`, use `$inject`:

```
account.controller('loginController', loginController);

...

loginController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function loginController($scope) {
...
}
```

Direct injection is only used when the body is inside `account.controller`.

```
account.controller('loginController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
...
}]);
```

Also, it seems your `account.js` file has an invalid IIFE - `(function(){...});` instead of `(function(){...})();`

Comment: Thanks,
It's worked when i change this (function(){...}); to (function(){...})();
It's just about IIFE, not the injection, but your answer is help me to get it work :)

Comment: The injection bit is also important. Otherwise if you minify your code, it might break.

Comment: Thanks for hint, i already know about injection problem when minify js files

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove $scope from the controller declaration as given below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var account = angular.module('account');
    account.controller('loginController', loginController);
    function loginController($scope) {
        $scope.Title = 'login';
    };
});
```